# Why does __slots__ = ('__dict__',) produce smaller instances?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

```
class Spam(object):
    __slots__ = ('__dict__',)
```

Produces instances smaller than those of a "normal" class. Why is this?

Source: [David Beazley's recent tweet](https://twitter.com/dabeaz/status/785948782219231232).

Comment: Aparently it's because [it's missing `__dir__`](https://twitter.com/TeemuRisikko/status/786202646994563077). As for why that happens, I have no idea.

Comment: It'd be better to update your question with an example.

Comment: The "why" is pretty obvious, the "how" is that python skips creating a per-object attribute `dict`. Your naming your attribute `__dict__` is a bit strange... if you do `self.__dict__ = {}` in your `__init__`, then you defeated the purpose of `__slots__`.

Comment: running dir on both slots and nonslots version - the only difference is the non-slot version has `__weakref__`, instead of `__slots__`, but they behave exactly the same from my tests

Comment: Can you explaing what  you are trying to achieve by using `__slots__` like this, and why you find this fact surprising?

Comment: Citing the source would have been polite.  I've edited it into the question.

Comment: Isn't the end result that you can have a slot/low-memory instance base to work with, which *also* supports arbitrary attribute assignment, once you have the \__dict\__ placeholder initiated to {}?  For example, you could be working with mostly read-only/low-mem tuples/ coming from a database.  But... if you want to assign *another* attribute to the instance under some conditions, then you are back to normal Python.

Comment: I had played around with something like that before switching to SQLAlchemy-based db access and it was a proper pain in the neck to use slots most of the time, but allow escalation to full Python attrib goodness when desired.  I also kinda recall I think it was Fluent Python (great book) talking about having your cake and eating it by combining __slots__ & __dict__ together.  Anyone tried that out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To me, it looks like the memory savings come from the lack of a `__weakref__` on the instance.

So if we have:

```
class Spam1(object):
    __slots__ = ('__dict__',)

class Spam2(object):
    __slots__ = ('__dict__', '__weakref__')

class Spam3(object):
    __slots__ = ('foo',)

class Eggs(object):
    pass

objs = Spam1(), Spam2(), Spam3(), Eggs()
for obj in objs:
    obj.foo = 'bar'

import sys
for obj in objs:
    print(type(obj).__name__, sys.getsizeof(obj))
```

The results (on python 3.5.2) are:

```
Spam1 48
Spam2 56
Spam3 48
Eggs 56
```

We see that `Spam2` (which has a `__weakref__`) is the same size as `Eggs` (a traditional class).

Note that normally, this savings is going to be completely insignificant (and prevents you from using weak-references in your slots enabled classes).  Generally, savings from `__slots__` come from the fact that they don't create a `__dict__` in the first place.  Since `__dict__` are implemented using a somewhat sparse table (in order to help avoid hash collisions and maintain O(1) lookup/insert/delete), there's a fair amount of space that isn't used for each dictionary that your program creates.  If you add `'__dict__'` to your `__slots__` though, you miss out on this optimization (a dict is still created).

To explore this a little more, we can add more slots:

```
class Spam3(object):
    __slots__ = ('foo', 'bar')
```

Now if we re-run, we see that it takes:

```
Spam1 48
Spam2 56
Spam3 56
Eggs 56
```

So each slot takes 8 bytes on the *instance* (for me -- likely because 8 bytes is `sizeof(pointer)` on my system).  Also note that `__slots__` is implemented by making descriptors (which live on the *class*, not the instance).  So, the instance (even though you might find `__slots__` listed via `dir(instance)`) isn't actually carrying around a `__slots__` value) -- That's being carried around by the *class*.

This also has the consequence that your slots enabled class can't set "default" values... e.g. the following code doesn't work:

```
class Foo(object):
    __slots__ = ('foo',)
    foo = 'bar'
```

So to boil it down:

- each "slot" on an instance takes up the size of a pointer on your system.
- without `__slots__ = ('__dict__',)` a `__dict__` slot and a `__weakref__` slot is created on the instance
- with `__slots__ = ('__dict__',)`, a `__dict__` slot is created but a `__weakref__` slot is not create on the instance.
- In neither case is `__slots__` actually put on the *instance*.  It lives on the *class* (even though you might see it from `dir(instance)`).
- The savings you reap from using `__slots__` in this way is likely to be insignificant.  Real savings from `__slots__` happen when you do not create a `dict` for the instance (since `dict` take up a more storage than the sum of the storage required for their contents due to somewhat sparse packing data in the data-structure).  On top of that, there are downsides to using slots this way (e.g. no weak-references to your instances).

Comment: It's because of the lack of but in other hand we have `__slots__` in other instance so the difference should be, equal with the difference of size of `__slots__` and `__weakref__` but it's not so!

Comment: @Kasramvd -- If I understand it correctly, `__slots__` creates descriptors on the _class_, so the `__slots__` doesn't really get carried around with an _instance_.  The instance just carries around a memory slot (`sizeof(pointer)`)  With weakref, I'm _guessing_ that `getsizeof` also adds a little overhead for the size of the `__weakref__` list -- Though it's pretty hard to track through the source what `getsizeof` is actually doing to tell you the numbers it is reporting :-)

Comment: Yes, the obvious thing is that the difference is because of the `__weakref__`  and `__slots__` which you mentioned. But it's not easy to find out that what's the exact reason of the difference. Specially at python level.

Comment: The simple answer to that is that a `__weakref__` slot is one more slot, and more slots take more space. The implementation-details answer is that a `__weakref__` slot causes Python to set the type's `tp_weaklistoffset` and add `sizeof(PyObject *)` to the fixed portion of the type's instance size.

Comment: You can see some of the code for that [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/typeobject.c#l2398), where a `__weakref__` slot name sets the flag that makes Python add the weak reference list to a type, and [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/typeobject.c#l2616), where Python decides where to put the weak reference list and increases the type's `tp_basicsize` to account for the space the weak reference list takes.

Comment: ...and the comment I was replying to vanished just before I posted. Looks like I was too slow.

Comment: @user2357112 -- Yeah, I resolved the general quote that the "`__weakref__` slot is one more slot" in my head and deleted the comment (though with less understanding of the deep internal workings which I'm glad you've provided here.)